# show calendar when editing date

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I'm writing a simple Qt program with a table view.
I have date fields in this element and I want to make the edit mode just like in QSqlTableModel.
When user clicks on the date appears calendar to edit.

Please help how to do that.
I created my own model forn QAbstractTableModel reimplemented rowcount/columncount/data/flags/headerData
Do I need something more?